# Error 405 - Metodo no permitido

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

Estoy desarrollando una WEB API, hice las pruebas en postman y el backend funciona correctamente tanto en el post, como en el get pero cuando lo ejecuto en el servidor, me aparece Error 405: Method not allowed.

Este el codigo en mi VCS:

```
/** Formulario para el registro de un nuevo usuario */

    $.ajax ({
        type: 'POST',
        //ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        headers: {
            "ContentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8" 
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(datos),

        URL: "http://localhost:8080/api/user/new",

        statusCode: function (response) {
            $("#txtName").val("");
            $("#txtEmail").val("");
            $("#txtPassword").val("");
       
            console.log(response);
            console.log("Created User");
            alert("Successfully register");
            window.location.reload()
        },

        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            window.location.reload()
            alert("It wasn't possible to create the account!");
        }
    });
}
```

[image: en el console dice el error 405: method not allowed, segun me dijo el profesor el error esta en el front, no el back. De hecho el back no muestra errores]

Comment: El JavaScript ejemplo es de lado del cliente cierto y este es el que te regresa 405?

Comment: Parece ser que no has configurado el backend para recibir el método post.

Comment: Si, el JavaScript es de lado del cliente y este es el que regresa el error 405. Y en el backend ya esta configurado el POST, de hecho desde el postman crea el usuario y funciona correctamente.

Comment: Pon todo el error que te aparece, tanto en el front como en el back.

Comment: alcanzas a ver en la imagen el error que envia el servidor?

Comment: Parece un problema de CORS. Sería un problema del lado servidor que solo aparece cuando el javascript de una página intenta una petición REST Ajax, y el servidor no tiene CORS correctamente configurado. El problema no aparece en cambio si el cliente es cualquier otro programa que no sea JS desde el navegador (por ejemplo, si el cliente es un programa Python o una extensión del navegador como Postman). Eso explicaría por qué te funciona con Postman pero no desde el html.

Comment: No quiero ver el "error que envía el servidor", quiero ver el error que **da en el servidor**. Si estás atacando una API, quiero ver qué pasa en la API, **qué** hace la api, **cómo** lo hace la api. Si no vemos el código, no sabemos qué está pasando. Si no podemos ver cómo lo tienes configurado solo podemos *especular* sobre qué *puede* estar pasando. Si quieres que te ayudemos, danos las herramientas para hacerlo, enséñanos todo lo que necesitamos ver, porque no estamos en tu pc ni somos adivinos :)

Answer (score 0):

En la documentación oficial

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Para las peticiones Ajax se usa “url” no “URL”

quizás sea eso revisa

Comment: Podría ser, pero si no encontrase URL a la que atacar, daría 404 no 405, imagino. Esta respuesta es más bien un comentario... te recomiendo leer [answer] y hacer el [tour] para entender cómo funciona SO y cómo elaborar respuestas de manera correcta, puesto que no somos un "foro" al uso. Bienvenido a SO :)

Comment: Si, es era el error, tenia URL y no url... Muchas Gracias!